# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C byte reader

Tags: c, linked-list, byte

I have an assignment for my intro to system operations class that has two distinct parts, the first being a simple program to read an executable, byte by byte, and output the strings entered that are at least 4 characters long. It is a simple modeling of the strings program (command) you can use in UNIX.

I'm having a segmentation fault (core dumped) error for three separate sample executables that I feed into it. I understand that this essentially means I'm trying to access some memory address that I do not have access to (either by overreaching the allocated block that the program owns, or by some other means). Unfortunately, I don't understand why this program is doing it.

I think the problem lies in the my linked list implementation - I use it to store the characters that are readable, and then check to see if the linked list has 4 entries when a non-readable character crops up. If it does, I print it. Then I clear the linked list and start again.

I'm traversing the file byte by byte, and I feel that the logic of this program is sound. However, my complete understanding of pointers, addresses, and malloc is not as sound. I have a hunch the segmentation fault is occurring because of this lack of knowledge.

Could someone look at the code below, and find out what I'm doing wrong? Most importantly, could you explain what concept I am misusing, and why? I'm worried about the program functioning the way it should, yes, but also worried about my lack of understanding. The code is below - thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char ANSII;
    struct node *next_node;
};

void clear_list(struct node *first_node);
void print(struct node *first_node);
int counter(struct node *first_node);
void append(char temp, struct node *first_node);


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *f = NULL;
    struct node header;
    char temp;

    if(argc != 2){ /* argv[0] = name of the program, argv[1] = file to open */
        printf("usage: %s filename:", argv[0]);
    }

    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(f == 0){ /* check for successful read */
         printf("Could not open file.\n");
    }

    while(!feof(f)){
        fread(&temp, sizeof(1), 1, f);
        if(temp >= 32 && temp <= 128){ /* If it falls between the bounds of printable     characters. */
            append(temp, &header); //Builds the string
        }else{
            if(counter(&header) > 3){
                print(&header);
            }
            clear_list(&header);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void clear_list(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor;
    while(first_node != NULL){
        conductor = first_node;
        while(conductor->next_node != NULL){
            conductor = conductor->next_node;
        }
        free(conductor);
    }
}
void print(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    while(conductor != 0){
        printf("%s", conductor->ANSII);
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int counter(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    int counter = 0;
    while(conductor != 0){
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
void append(char temp, struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    while(conductor->next_node != 0){
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
    }
    conductor->next_node = malloc(sizeof(conductor->next_node));
    if(conductor->next_node == 0){
        printf("Memory allocation failed!");
        return;
    }
    conductor = conductor->next_node;
    conductor->ANSII = temp;
}
```

I tried implementing the answers so far, and now instead of a segmentation fault I'm getting:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./mystrings: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000601250   ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3886a75916]
./mystrings[0x400798]
./mystrings[0x40072f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3886a1ecdd]
./mystrings[0x4005b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:1b 1921384528                         /afs/pitt.edu/home/n/a/nap54/private/cs449/project2/mystrings
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:1b 1921384528                              /afs/pitt.edu/home/n/a/nap54/private/cs449/project2/mystrings
00601000-00622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3886600000-3886620000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
388681f000-3886820000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3886820000-3886821000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3886821000-3886822000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3886a00000-3886b89000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886b89000-3886d89000 ---p 00189000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886d89000-3886d8d000 r--p 00189000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886d8d000-3886d8e000 rw-p 0018d000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-   2.12.so
3886d8e000-3886d93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
388d200000-388d216000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20120305.so.1
388d216000-388d415000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-  4.4.6-20120305.so.1
388d415000-388d416000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-    4.4.6-20120305.so.1
7ffff7fd5000-7ffff7fd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffea000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now I'm completely lost. Could someone shed (more?) insight? Thanks for your help guys...

Comment: Don't do `while (!feof(...))`. Do e.g. `while (fread(...) != 0)`.

Comment: If I do while (fread(...) != 0), won't it consume the character, and I won't be able to capture the byte?

Comment: Just move the current `fread` call to be the one inside the `while` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare the variable `header`, you do not initialize the members. This means that the values of those will be undefined and random. Then when you call `append` the `next_node` member is most likely not `NULL` leading you do dereference an undefined pointer and have undefined behavior.

Initialize at least the `next_node` member of the `header` structure in `main`.