# Run-time crash in C program mimicking 'strings' UNIX command

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

Follow up of the original program: [Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C byte reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374989/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-c-byte-reader)

My program is supposed to sort of mimic (in a primitive way), but currently isn't working.

I've been working on this for a decent amount of time, and previously I was getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) due to an uninitialized node that I use as the first_node, or because of the way I had previously used feof() instead of fread(...) != 0. I've implemented both of the suggestions that were given my question from last night, but now I'm even more at a loss that before. I'm not quite sure what this error means even, let alone why I am getting it. Below is my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char ANSII;
    struct node *next_node;
};

void clear_list(struct node *first_node);
void print(struct node *first_node);
int counter(struct node *first_node);
void append(char temp, struct node *first_node);


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *f = NULL;
    struct node header;
    char temp;

    if(argc != 2){ /* argv[0] = name of the program, argv[1] = file to open */
        printf("usage: %s filename:", argv[0]);
    }

    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");

    if(f == 0){ /* check for successful read */
         printf("Could not open file.\n");
    }

    while(!feof(f)){
        fread(&temp, sizeof(1), 1, f);
        if(temp >= 32 && temp <= 128){ /* If it falls between the bounds of printable     characters. */
            append(temp, &header); //Builds the string
        }else{
            if(counter(&header) > 3){
                print(&header);
            }
            clear_list(&header);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
void clear_list(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor;
    while(first_node != NULL){
        conductor = first_node;
        while(conductor->next_node != NULL){
            conductor = conductor->next_node;
        }
        free(conductor);
    }
}
void print(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    while(conductor != 0){
        printf("%s", conductor->ANSII);
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int counter(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    int counter = 0;
    while(conductor != 0){
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
void append(char temp, struct node *first_node){
    struct node *conductor = first_node;
    while(conductor->next_node != 0){
        conductor = conductor->next_node;
    }
    conductor->next_node = malloc(sizeof(conductor->next_node));
    if(conductor->next_node == 0){
        printf("Memory allocation failed!");
        return;
    }
    conductor = conductor->next_node;
    conductor->ANSII = temp;
}
```

I tried implementing the answers so far, and now instead of a segmentation fault I'm getting the following run-time crash:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./mystrings: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000601250   ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3886a75916]
./mystrings[0x400798]
./mystrings[0x40072f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3886a1ecdd]
./mystrings[0x4005b9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:1b 1921384528                         /afs/pitt.edu/home/n/a/nap54/private/cs449/project2/mystrings
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:1b 1921384528                              /afs/pitt.edu/home/n/a/nap54/private/cs449/project2/mystrings
00601000-00622000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3886600000-3886620000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
388681f000-3886820000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3886820000-3886821000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 180                            /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3886821000-3886822000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3886a00000-3886b89000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886b89000-3886d89000 ---p 00189000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886d89000-3886d8d000 r--p 00189000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3886d8d000-3886d8e000 rw-p 0018d000 fd:00 183                            /lib64/libc-   2.12.so
3886d8e000-3886d93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
388d200000-388d216000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.6-20120305.so.1
388d216000-388d415000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-  4.4.6-20120305.so.1
388d415000-388d416000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 6639                           /lib64/libgcc_s-    4.4.6-20120305.so.1
7ffff7fd5000-7ffff7fd8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffff7ffe000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffea000-7ffffffff000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now I'm completely lost. Could someone shed (more?) insight? Thanks for your help guys, I haven't gotten much (any sleep) last night and this project (along with the more important second portion of it) is due at midnight tonight... I understand that I'm just kind of pasting my code and saying 'have at it', but I'm really not sure where to begin, as this is my first time experiencing a crash such as this.

Comment: about `feof`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clear_list` function frees the tail of the list then repeats.  Once it reaches the point where there is only a single node remaining, it repeatedly tries to free `first_node`.  `clear_list` could be more simply written as

```
void clear_list(struct node *first_node){
    struct node *ptr = first_node;
    struct node *next;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        next = ptr->next_node;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = next;
    }
}
```

Another issue, originally pointed out by Grijesh Chauhan, is that the line

```
printf("%s", conductor->ANSII);
```

is wrong.  `conductor->ANSII` has type `char` so you should use the `%c` format specifier to print its value.

Comment: I didn't notice this problem, add print issue also(deleted my answer). my vote limit reached today so consider for both of your answer pending :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Were you suggesting that I add the `printf` format specifier bug you spotted to my answer?  I've done this now.  Please feel free to edit my answer if that isn't what you wanted.

Comment: @simcon Yes this is what I wanted you to add in your answer. This is another issue in `print(){..}` function. I think OP was unaware of this at time he posted question. But it is not for which he asked question so I deleted my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - this also makes sense, and that is a clever way to use two pointers to simplify and more efficiently clear the linked list!

Answer (score 2):

You really ought to learn how to use a debugger like `gdb` or other.

One obvious problem is that you do not initialize the `next` field in the `header` structure. So when you go to append, it starts going through it and who knows where it might end up (do not assume the fields are initialized to 0)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I forgot that I had updated my code from last night (where I drew the code from) to initialize the next field. I appreciate the help though!

Answer (score 1):

You used `sizeof` twice and both of them are wrong.

`sizeof(1)` is the size of an `int`, because 1 is an `int` constant. Most likely to be 4, with the typical 8-bit bytes and 32-bit `int`s. So your `fread` is trying to read 4 bytes into a single char. That's bad.

In the other one, you've almost used the recommended safe `sizeof` idiom for `malloc`:

```
p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

but you forgot the `*`. So you're allocating enough space to hold the pointer to the struct, not enough to hold the struct.

```
conductor->next_node = malloc(sizeof(*conductor->next_node));
```

Comment: Completely right - the 1 was just a typo/logical error that must of occurred out of carelessness. But I didn't even realize that I was doing the malloc incorrectly for the new struct, I appreciate the clarification and reasoning. It was really helpful to my understanding.